# make this event happen when the page loads - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

below is the code that performs an action on mouseover. I want that action to occur when the page loads.

```
$(window).load(function() 
{

$(".rokclass").hover(
function () { 
$(this).attr('src', 'images/xyz.gif'); 

} 

);
});
```

Comment: [TAB key](http://i.imgur.com/jKQau.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rokclass').attr('src','images/xyz.gif');
});
```

If you're planning to use this code when the document loads and also in the mouseover event, consider placing it in a function you can call in both places.

Comment: can you tell me what actually this code does when executed. it replaces the image, does it?

Comment: Yeah. Assuming that you have an image with a class name of "rokclass" then this code replaces its src attribute value with a new value.